# Can I use free SQLServer Express in commercial app

Tags: sql

Can I use free SQLServer Express in my commercial windows project? Are there any license issues? How many nodes it supports in multiuser environment ?

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 27):

Quick answer is Yes. I have heard of MS themselves say it is OK. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/39b04633-0a09-4d8f-b679-33effe154cdc/) MSDN forums thread.

Answer (score 16):

SQL Server Express is distributed for free and can be used reliably in any small business application.

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) article is quite good at highlighting the key drawbacks of using an Express edition compared to a commercial SQL Server instance. Most notable perhaps is the lack of a SQL Server Agent process, which is usually used for job scheduling.