# SQL Server Express localdb.msi offline installer

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I am not able to install using the online installer. Can anyone point me to where I can find the offline installer? I tried searching with Google gut with no luck.

This is similar but not an offline installer.

[How to install localdb separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately)

This is the error I encounter repeatedly using the online installer
(probably due to the firewall):
[image]

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Go to this page:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express

Click the download link to download and launch the 5 MB installer.

In the Installer, select "Download Media"

[image]

Direct URL: https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/0/7/907AD35F-9F9C-43A5-9789-52470555DB90/ENU/SqlLocalDB.msi

Direct URL for SQL Server 2017 LocalDb: https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/F/2/EF23C21D-7860-4F05-88CE-39AA114B014B/SqlLocalDB.msi

**UPD 2019-03: Current LocalDB version has a [bug](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191393/localdb-v14-creates-wrong-path-for-mdf-files?newreg=facdb435c0f4466892c1108555af7587) which can be fixed by installing the latest Cumulative Update (CU)

Comment: The online installer doesn't work in my environment.

Comment: I have added a direct URL

Comment: How on earth did you find these links? Also, are these 32 or 64 bit installers?

Comment: I used Fiddler. And both are 64 bit indtallers

Comment: So you started SQL Server Express installer and captured all the traffic with Fiddler? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: any chance you have the direct URL for SQL 2017 Express Core and Advanced? I tried to download but it is blocked somehow by my company's proxy

Comment: @addicted - you can find them by using Fiddler

Comment: it was almost impossible to find online links. thanks sql server 2017 worked for me.

Comment: PowerShell: `Select-String sqllocaldb.msi ./SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe -Context 5 `.

Comment: where can I find the 32-bit version?
I assume I'll need to distribute both.

Comment: @PhilPreen There is no 32 bit version

Comment: OK. So the 64-bit version will work on 32-bit Windows?

Comment: No, you must use an older edition if you need 32 bit support

Comment: OK. Looks like I'll need to ship with LocalDB 2014. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to update this localdb install with the latest CU doesn't appear to work. Have you see this behavior? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811000/patching-sql-server-localdb

Answer (score 8):

For SQL Server 2022 LocalDB (en-US) the URL is: https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/d/38de7036-2433-4207-8eae-06e247e17b25/SqlLocalDB.msi

If you want other languages, my technique for finding the URLs is here:
https://blog.dotsmart.net/2022/11/24/sql-server-2022-localdb-download/

Answer (score 3):

for those who seek 32 bit edition localDB for download, here it is:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/D/D/8DD7BDBA-CEF7-4D8E-8C16-D9F69527F909/ENU/x86/SqlLocaLDB.MSI