# sql server installer for express editions has stopped working (sql server 2016)

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2016

When trying to install **SQL Server Express Edition** (2016) on a Windows server, downloading the file **SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe** from Microsoft and trying to run it causes the following error (the installation process doesn't even start):

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the full download of **SQL Server Express** using the link posted on [SQL Server® 2016 Express full download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835986/sql-server-2016-express-full-download), and then trying to run the program caused the following error:

[image]

It seems that this version of SQL Server requires at least **Windows Server 2012** or Windows 8 whereas the server was running Windows Server 2008 R2.

You should either try installing an earlier version of SQL Server such as 2014 or get a server with a newer version of Windows.