# Licensing of LocalDB on a small commercial product

Tags: sql-server, localdb

As LocalDB seemed to be a nice and simple relational solution for a small amount of data, we thought it would be a simple yet effective solution for our relatively small commercial product.

Now, as the product is close to its release, we are concerned whether or not it would be appropriate to use it on client's workstations or there should be any changes. We are mainly concerned about issues like licensing.

After doing some research, I came to the following conclusions:

1. LocalDB [is a part of the SQL Local Express](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92948/what-is-needed-to-deploy-an-application-that-uses-microsofts-new-localdb).
2. SQL Express [can be used in commercial apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011716/can-i-use-free-sqlserver-express-in-commercial-app).

Therefore it seemed logical that LocalDB could be used in production without licensing issues. Considering though that licensing can be a very strict field, we still have concerns on this.

Apart from that, we are wondering if there are there any other big drawbacks on using LocalDB in production, considering our project contains a small amount of data and not the requirement of any need for centralized deployment.

So, the main question is, are we allowed to use LocalDB in a commercial product and, if yes, are there any big drawbacks to this usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the smallest edition of SQL Server Express instead, as LocalDB does not allow remote (network) connections. Both "SQL Server Express" and "SQL Server Express LocalDB" are [free to download and distribute](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2016-pricing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please echance it in order to answer more about the licensing part?