# Microsoft SQL express for production use?

Tags: sql-server-express

My team currently designing an accounting system(First module) for a small business. When I was checking the price of the Microsoft SQL I was stunt because it was so expensive and the business will surely not carry that price. Then I remember that there is a free version of Microsoft SQL. I Know that there are limitations but Is it advisable to use the Microsoft SQL express?

Comment: That's why Microsoft SQL Server isn't feasible for small businesses. :-)

Comment: Is there any database that is free and us powerful as SQL?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I will check that later.

Comment: Please call it Microsoft SQL not SQL.

Comment: @dashmug already corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MS SQL Server Express for commercial use.

there are many companies use the express free version as the main database for their products

You can also have a look at this link might help as well

[Can I use free SQLServer Express in commercial app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011716/can-i-use-free-sqlserver-express-in-commercial-app)

Comment: I know that I can use the Microsoft SQL express for commercial use but I was thinking but is it advisable because of the limitation.